# Differences in output from hexdump and hexedit

Tags: linux, assembly, arm, hexdump, hex-editors

I have been experimenting in arm assembly, and looking at the hexedecimal output produced by the assembler. Now when I assembled this:

```
.byte 0xff
.word 0x11111111
```

I was expecting an output of `ff11 1111 11` but looking at in hexdump showed me this: `11ff 1111 0011` at first I was confused, and thought maybe I had discovered some obscurity in my assembler (obviously I have not used the .align directive here, so this code would be incorrect in a real-life usage, and I thought the assembler might be doing something weird because of this). However when I went and checked the output using the program hexedit (if you are unfamiliar with this it is just a simple command line hexeditor), and it showed me what I expected (`ff 11 11 11 11`). Does anyone know why I am receiving this odd output? Is this a bug in hexdump, or does hexdump not behave like I am expecting it to for some other reason?

Comment: Try adding the `-C` flag to hexdump.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hexdump show content `ff11` as `11ff` because of [little-endian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) byte order.